# Javascript with jQuery transition of nav element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first ever attempt to write a js to control a DOM element which failed to "slide" this HTML5 nav element in and out of the left edge of the mobile phone screen.
I would appreciate some help to get it to work and some polishing up. Thanks

```js
$("header .ui-btn-left").click(function() {
   var left = $("nav").offset().left;
   var width = $("nav").width();
   if (left == 0) {
      // $("nav").css({"left": -width});
      $("nav").css({transition: left -width 0.3s ease});
   } else {
      $("nav").css({"left": 0});
   }
});
```

```css
nav {
   width: 80%;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: white;
   left: 0;
   top: 2em;
}
```

```html
   <body>

      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-bars">Menu</a>
         <h1>My App</h1>
      </header>

      <div data-role="content" class="contentDiv">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         <main>
            <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> -->
         </main><!-- /main content -->
   
         <nav>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
               <li><a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="France" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">France</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Germany" class="ui-li-icon">Germany</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Great Britain" class="ui-li-icon">Great Britain</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Finland" class="ui-li-icon">Finland</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="United States" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">United States</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav><!-- /side navigation -->
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">NO</button></li>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">EXTRA</button></li>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">YES</button></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </footer><!-- footer -->
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your snippet. Are you missing something? `:)`

Comment: Wheres your html? $("nav") would refer to a <nav></nav> tag and $("header") would refer to <header></header>. Is that your intention? If you meant to refer to an element with id="nav" you would refer to it as $("#nav")

Comment: Yes. it is working but the transition functionality is what is not working. I will put the relevant HTML and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS transition property does not take an actual CSS property value, for instance `left 30px`. Also you did not quote the transition property value so you should actually have a syntax error on your console.

```
$("nav").css({transition: 'left 0.3s ease'});
$("nav").css({"left": -width});
```

Also you can just put the transition property into your CSS style sheet unless you plan to modify it to a different setting.

```js
jQuery("button").click(function(){
   var left = $("nav").offset().left;
   var width = $("nav").width();
   if (left == 0) {
      $("nav").css({"left": -width});
   } else {
      $("nav").css({"left": 0});
   }
});
```

```css
nav {
  position:fixed;
  left:-300px;
  top:0px;
  width:300px;
  transition:left 0.3s ease;
}
button {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  some nav
</nav>
<button>show/hide</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `max-width:` and `animate()`

in css

```
nav{
   max-width : 0px;
}
```

in js

```
$("header .ui-btn-left").click(function() {
   var Width = $("nav").outerWidth();
   if (Width == 0) {
      $("nav").animate({"max-width": "1000px"} , 1000);
   } else {
      $("nav").animate({"max-width": "0px"} , 1000);
   }
});
```

[**Simple Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/x89chpt3/)